# is there a way to use JMS (java message service) on ESP32?

Tags: java, jms, esp32

I'm trying to build an application in which I want to use the JMS (java message service). Unfortunately, I'm unable to find any libraries specifically for ESM32-WROOM online. So, can anyone help me with how can I build the JMS stack for ESM32-WROOM on my own if it's possible!. In my application, the ESP32-WROOM will get messages from the server every second.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in your question, JMS is the **Java** Message Service so in order to use it you'd need to use Java which would require a Java Virtual Machine (i.e. JVM). The JVM is a sophisticated piece of software which is almost certainly not supported on ESP32.

Most JMS providers also support other protocols for IoT devices like ESP32. For example, ActiveMQ Artemis supports JMS as well as MQTT (among other protocols). MQTT is a protocol specifically created for small sensors and mobile devices. It is optimized for high-latency or unreliable networks which makes it a good fit for IoT devices. I recommend you use MQTT on your device if possible. Take a look at the [ESP32 MQTT Library](https://github.com/espressif/esp-mqtt).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll switch to MQTT for fast development. On the other hand, I'm not completely sure but the JMS is an application layer service which uses the TCP/ IP Client/ Server protocol at the communication layer. So, with enough of procedural details, building a stack won't be an issue.